# having an html file downloaded instead of displayed

Tags: html, http, web-applications

I am writing a web based files administrator. How can I have an html file be downloaded when its link is clicked instead of displayed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On server side, when serving file, add this header:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="document.html"
```

For examle in PHP you'd do:

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="document.html"');
```

Answer (score 0):

In the response headers, set Content-Disposition to "attachment; filename=something.html"

Answer (score -1):

Set the Content-Type header on your HTTP response to 'application/octet-stream'.

In ASP.net/C#

```
Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
```

Answer (score -1):

The server would need to return a different MIME Type when that file is requested such as application/octet-stream.